# How to include date in fwrite?

Tags: php, forms, email, fwrite

I currently have an fwrite below which occurs when a form is filled out, I want to put the current date the form was filled out within the fwrite, how would I do this?

```
fwrite($fh, "$firstname\r\n $lastname\r\n $email\r\n $zipcode\r\n $feedback\r\n \r\n");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
fwrite($fh, "$firstname\r\n $lastname\r\n $email\r\n $zipcode\r\n $feedback\r\n $date\r\n \r\n");
```